# Why Displaying all records after multi_query running in MySQLi with PHP doesnt work but single query does?

Tags: php, mysqli

Making a simple program of inserting multiple records in database and then showing whole table should probably have code like this:

[image: Error Giving Code.]

but is giving following error:

[image: Error Given By above code]

But, same code works when only one record is inserted and nothing else is changed.

```
<?php
$con=new mysqli("localhost","root","","lamkp");
if($con->connect_error)
    die("error is: ".$con->connect_error);
else
    echo "Connected!<br>";
/*
$ins="insert into teting values ('a');";
$ins.="insert into teting values ('b');";
$ins  .="insert into teting values ('c');";
if ($con->multi_query($ins)===true) {
    echo "Inserted all";
}*/
$ins="insert into teting values ('A word')";
if ($con->query($ins)===true) {
    echo "Inserted word";
}
else
    die("Error: ".$con->error);

$q="select * from teting";
echo "<table border=1>";
$run=$con->query($q);
if($run->num_rows>0){
    while ($result=$run->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td>".$result["name"]."</td></tr>";
    }
}
else
    die("Error: ".$con->error);
echo "</table>";

?>
```

Engine: InnoDB

What could be the cause of problem and solution of course?

Comment: What database storage engine is in use?

Comment: @SpacePhoenix InnoDB

Comment: What happens if you add `while ($con->next_result()) {}` before `$run=$con->query($q);`?